# Scraping latitude and longitude data from Google Map embedded on an Airbnb room listing

Tags: google-maps, web-scraping

I'm wondering how to scrape latitude and longitude data from the embedded google map on Airbnb listing.
The example link: `https://www.airbnb.jp/rooms/11171169.` 
There is a map embedded in the listing and I cannot find latitude and longitude data from the HTML easily.

Thanks

Comment: If you step through the HTML, you'll find the lat/lng as part of the `a href` for the Google logo in the bottom left corner (in this case, 35.646979,139.709182).  That will give you map center.  From there, you can overlay your own circle.

Comment: Great, thanks! Exactly what I wanted to know :)